# Issue with calling function that takes in three parameters, one being int const

Tags: c++

I'm posting because I'm having issues figuring out why my "total aid available" is not printing the total of the pell grant, stafford loan, and work-study loan. I've tried fixing my function again and again (I used sources online and in reference book, but I don't know if the issue is that my function won't be called or not, since nothing is printing for the total aid available.

Everything else is fine, except that one thing, and it is really bugging me since no matter what changes I make, I'm in the same state. No errors showing either. I'm using microsoft visual studio for the first time as compiler, so I wonder if that is the issue.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double pell_Grant(double); // forward declaration on pell_Grant ( which is a       function for calculating pell grant)

double sum(double, int const, double); // declaration for sum function which   gives total for the total aid available

int main()
{

double workstudy = 0, pellgrant = 5730, grossincome = 0, Total = 0; //  variables 
int yes;
int const stafford = 9500; //const declaration
cout << "Lemme Forecast Your FAFSA" << endl;

cout << "Enter your adjusted gross income: " << endl; cin >> grossincome; //  input for gross income

if (grossincome >= 30000) // if gross income is higher than 30,000 then print message
{
    cout << "Sorry Charlie, your income is too high to run this  forecaster!";
    return 0;
}

cout << "Can someone claim you as a dependent? [1=yes/0=no]: " << endl; // input to claim dependent or not
cin >> yes;
if (yes == 1) // if 1 for yes is selected then pell grant gets reduced by 750, if 0 or no selected, then program goes by standard procedure
{
    pellgrant -= 750;
}

workstudy = 1465; // work study must be nationwide avergae 1,465
if (grossincome >= 19000) // if this condition is met then work study is not met and message is printed as follows...
{
    cout << "Your Work-Study Award is not available for your income level" << endl;
    workstudy = 0;
}

double foo = pell_Grant(grossincome); // value returned from pell_Grant stored here to give total

Total = sum(workstudy + stafford + pellgrant); // sum function is called and stores result in Total

if (workstudy != 0) // if work study loan isn't more than 19,000 then it will be calculated and printed in next statement
{
    cout << "Your Work-Study Award (if available)= " << workstudy << endl;
}
cout << "Your Stafford Loan award (if needed)= " << stafford << endl; // prints stafford loan (const called)
cout << "Your Pell Grant= " << pellgrant << endl; // prints pell grant
cout << "Total Aid Available For You=" << Total << endl; // prints total

return (0);
}


double  pell_Grant(double x) // pell_Grant function that calculates pell grant which is assigned 5,730 
{
// x is gross income which is assigned 5,730. This is money received that does not need to be repaid.  
 if ((x > 12000) && (x < 20000)) // statement makes sure adjusted gross is  bettween 12000 & 20000
 {
    double a = x / 1000; // for every 1,000 in adjusted gross income... reduce/subtract 400 from it
        a *= 400;
    x -= a;
 }

if (x > 20000) // check if gross income is more than 20000
{
    double  a = x / 1000; // for every 1,000 in gross income, subtract 500
    a *= 500;
    x -= a;
}
return x;
}


double sum(double workstudy , int const stafford, double pellgrant) // function for adding up workstudy loan, stafford loan, and pellgrant loan
{
double Total;

Total = workstudy + stafford + pellgrant; 

return (Total); // returns total
}
```

Comment: Maybe putting `,` instead of `+` as the argument separators when invoking `sum` would help. Either that or post the *real* code. I officially don't buy the "No errors showing either" claim whatsoever.

Comment: `sum(workstudy + stafford + pellgrant)` This doesn't call a function with three parameters. This attempts to call a function with one parameter - which should produce an error as no such function was declared.

Comment: I created a new project on Visual studio to see because yeah I got no compile error before, and got the error message displayed, don't know why it didn't show before hand. Yeah thank you, I think I'll try to fix the code now.

Answer (score 2):

According to its declaration, the method `sum()` accepts 3 parameters.

```
double sum(double, int const, double);
```

But while calling you are passing only 1 parameter:

```
Total = sum(workstudy + stafford + pellgrant);
```

Instead, you need to pass 3 parameters, like this:

```
Total = sum(workstudy, stafford, pellgrant);
```

But, I don't understand why you aren't getting any errors! You are trying to call a non-existent function. You must get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your sum() function incorrectly.  This is your code:

```
Total = sum(workstudy + stafford + pellgrant); // sum function is called and stores result in Total
```

But your sum() function has three parameters.  The correct form to call the function would be:

```
Total = sum(workstudy, stafford, pellgrant); // sum function is called and stores result in Total
```